# Can this cause a race condition in Event Sourcing

Tags: php, event-sourcing

We are using Event Sourcing (specifically PHP, Laravel & Spatie's EventSourcing library, but I think my question pertains to Event Sourcing in general)

We have two Projectors - (ie, "Listeners" with code that will run)

```
ProjectorA::onEnrollmentCreated(){
    // does a db update to set status to 'pending'
}

ProjectorB::onEnrollmentCreated(){
    // does some own code, AND THEN records event `onEnrollmentApproved`,
    // which does a db update to set status to 'approved'
}
```

For this question, I think this is enough code to show. **The desired effect is that the enrollment ends up with status "approved"**

My question is:

To me, these listeners seem like asynchronously running functions, and so it is possible for there to be a hiccup in ProjectorA which would cause it to finish last and set the status back to "pending"

My teammate says that the way the projectors work, onEnrollmentCreated will always complete before onEnrollmentApproved is allowed to start. This makes no sense to me at all, and so my question is:

Can you explain this to me, or give me some links I can read more deeply about this particular aspect of Event Sourcing?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. There is no real guarantee that `ProjectorB` is alway run after `ProjectorA`. Although events do run in a synchronous manner by default(unless tweaked) but not projectors listening to them.

To manage the order, you can add a `weight` property to your projector class and make sure that your projector class doesn't implement `ShouldQueue` interface as mentioned in the [`docs`](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-event-sourcing/v7/using-projectors/making-sure-events-get-handled-in-the-right-order#content-tweaking-projector-order).

**Quoting from there:**

> You can add a weight property to a projector to tweak the order
> projectors are run in. Projectors with a lower weight run first. When
> no explicit weight is provided, the weight is considered 0.

```
namespace App\Projectors;

use Spatie\EventSourcing\EventHandlers\Projectors\Projector;

class MyProjector extends Projector
{
    public int $weight = 5;
    
    //
}
```

Comment: Do this actually mean the first project will *finish* before the second is called, or only start firing in that order? I think it means the second, but I'm not clear from the docs

Comment: @jmadsen If you add `weight` as `1` for `ProjectorA` and `2` for `ProjectorB`, they will execute in this order. They are synchronous in nature, meaning next will execute after the current is done, but the order of projectors being executed can't be guaranteed if you don't add weight.

Comment: sorry, you said that but it didn't sink in - thanks!